# How to retrieve an element from an array that is inside an object in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the structure of my Firestore DB:
[image: structure]

I have multiple arrays in the object "reserved items". Each array has more than one element stored in there.
How do I retrieve the "returnDate" element from each/every single array that is in the object?

Answer (score 1):

`reserved_items` is a field of type Array, and each element of this Array is a map/JS Object. You therefore have to iterate over the JavaScript Array representing this field and use the [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors). Here is an example with the [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method:

```
  var docRef = db.collection('...').doc('63ufq....');

  docRef
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        const reserved_items = doc.get('reserved_items');

        reserved_items.forEach(element => console.log(element.returnDate));

      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log('No such document!');
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting document:', error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, load your document from your firestore.

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

now, in doc.data() is your object, which has the 'reserved_items' as property.
Then you can use the map() function to iterate your 'reserved_items' and store the needed data in a variable